# How to interleave two lists in Haskell in one line with higher-order functions

Tags: haskell

I want to take two lists and return the interleaved list using one line of code.

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave xs ys = concat (zipWith (:) xs ys)
```

not sure why this isn't working.

Got it:

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave xs ys = concat (zipWith (\x y -> [x]++[y]) xs ys)
```

Comment: Look at the type of `(:)`: `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. Since `xs` and `ys` are both lists of `a`s, you are applying `:` to two elements of type `a`.

Comment: Is there another function that would allow me to prepend each element of xs onto the respective element of ys?

Comment: @user3046635, in addition to Eric's comment, consider what should happen if one list is shorter (remember that [zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip)-based functions trim the excess)

Comment: @user3046635, also, I would first write it NOT as a single line, and then try to make it shorter; first, to see that I can get it right, and second because oftentimes the multi-line version is so much easier to understand

Comment: BTW, `[x]++[y]` is the same as `[x,y]`

Answer (score 11):

You might also like

```
interleave xs ys = concat (transpose [xs, ys])
```

This is based on the observation I read ages ago (I can't remember where now -- perhaps in the Python documentation) that transposition is just an n-way zip.

Comment: it depends what you do with lists of different lengths; but awesome nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I really like this page to sort of play with the mechanics of the functions in haskell (gets your brain going also)

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

One of the examples is:

```
pl \(a,b) -> a:b:[]  
uncurry ((. return) . (:))
```

so you can also do:

```
[ghci] ((. return) . (:)) 1 2
[1,2]
[ghci] concat $ zipWith ((. return) . (:)) [1..10] [11..20]
[1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14,5,15,6,16,7,17,8,18,9,19,10,20]
```

Daniel Wagner's is much cleaner though :)

Answer (score 1):

Codegolf!

Here's how to interleave two lists of same length (truncating the longer of the two lists, as all solutions based on `zipWith` do):

```
f = (foldr($)[].).zipWith((.(:)).(.).(:))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you require is `(\a b-> a:b:[])` which is so trivial that I doubt there is something explicitely provided in Haskell that will do it. You can always define your own ...

```
[ghci] let (#) a b = [a,b]
[ghci] 3 # 4
[3,4]
[ghci] concat  ( zipWith (#) [1,2,3] [5,6,7] )
[1,5,2,6,3,7]
[ghci]
```

Comment: Quick note: `#` is a keyword in Haskell, so dont use it. But you get the idea ...

Comment: I had to do it in one line. I'm studying for an exam and the study guide has no answer key, but thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @ssm I was not aware that `#` is a reserved symbol in Haskell, can you elaborate?  I know that it's used to indicate unboxed types such as `Int#`, but then it is part of the type name, not anything special itself.

Comment: In that case, replace `(#)` with `(\a b -> [a,b])`. Thats what the lambda functions are for ...

Comment: @bheklilr: I didnt know either. So I hoogled ... http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%23. Thats whre I learned that that was a keyword.

Comment: @ssm Ah, that's what I'm referring to.  You actually have to enable the `MagicHash` extension to use it, and it works only at the kind level, so it's safe to use at the function level.  I believe I've even seen people define `(#) = flip ($)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `interleave xs ys = concatMap (\(x, y)->[x, y]) (zipWith (,) xs ys)`.  The `zipWith` subexpression converts the two lists into a list of tuples like `[(x0, y0), (x1, y1)]` and the `concatMap` converts them to a list.

Comment: `zipWith (,)` is the same as just `zip`. So you could write this as `concatMap (\(a,b)->[a,b]) $ zip xs ys`. But I prefer `zip xs ys >>= \(a,b)->[a,b]`, which avoids quite a bit of unnecessary punctuation.